# WordPress Theme-Editor - Update File button is unclickable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Suddenly a strange issue appeared in the WordPress Theme-Editor page. The Update File button at the bottom changes its position up and down when I try to click it! The issue is present no matter what theme is active.

I have inspected the button and found that when I disable this css it will work fine (load-styles.php):

.wp-core-ui p .button {vertical-align: baseline;}

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin is almost certainly adding some CSS to the selector `.button` or `.spinner` (the only other element with the same vertical-align parent). Disable all of your plugins and reactivate them one by one until you find the culprit. I was able to recreate the issue by adding `height: 100px;` to `.spinner`.

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling WordPress and making sure you have the most recent version.

Comment: I found the plugin by disabling all and enable one by one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Xhynk is right, there should be plugin conflicting with wordpress script or you have old version of WordPress, but make sure to take a backup to update WordPress.